# I can not import rumps in python 3 i get an error about mapping

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

trying to just import rumps in python 3 on osx monterey and getting this error. I tried pip3 install mapping, installing pyobjc and i can't get anything to work. i have python version 3.10.4

````
  File "/Users/Aphixe/PycharmProjects/lightmenubar/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import rumps
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rumps/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .rumps import (separator, debug_mode, alert, notification, application_support, timers, quit_application, timer,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rumps/rumps.py", line 33, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping, Iterable
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)```
````

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jaredks/rumps/issues/169#issuecomment-983439317

> Replacing
> `from collections import Mapping, Iterable`
> with
> `from collections.abc import Mapping, Iterable, MutableMapping`
> in
> `rumps.py` did the trick.

you can find where rumps is installed by using `pip3 list -v` in terminal